# Compare dates between rows from the same input file based on ID and replicate rows by increment date using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I am trying to duplicate rows by comparing the date of the current row with date of the next row for a user ID and row should be duplicated by incrementing the date where **< date of the next row.**

To explain in detail

input:-

[image]

Compare **Start_DateMonth** of first row with second row and replicate the row by incrementing the **Start_DateMonth** till the **Start_DateMonth** **of the second row of the input**

Expected Output:-

[image]

Please suggest if this logic can be implemented using SQL Server.

Comment: I removed the `mysql` tag based on the title of the question, that mentions MS SQL. These are two different databases, and you should be tagging only one.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Do you want a picture of the query or text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to use a recursive query:

```
with cte (user_id, start_datemonth, start_dateday, lead_start_datemonth) as (
    select 
        user_id, 
        start_datemonth, 
        start_dateday, 
        lead(start_datemonth) over(partition by user_id order by start_datemonth) lead_start_datemonth
    from mytable 
    union all
    select 
        user_id,
        start_datemonth + 1,
        start_dateday,
        lead_start_datemonth
    from cte
    where start_datemonth + 1 < lead_start_datemonth
)
select user_id, start_datemonth, start_dateday from cte
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=65c0ca54525cd58f80db9e4f6ae0a124)**:

```
 user_id | start_datemonth | start_dateday
-------: | --------------: | ------------:
11110002 |          210601 |             1
11110002 |          210602 |             1
11110002 |          210603 |             1
11110002 |          210604 |             2
11110002 |          210605 |             2
11110002 |          210606 |             2
11110002 |          210607 |             4
```

Comment: Now the logic is working for the rows except the last row as the lead(start_datemonth) is retreiving NULL for the last row.I I have a date column LastworkingDate. Pls suggest how can we modify this code as the start_datemonth of last row will increment till the LastworkingDate. Also when the Date increments, after 201612 the next date should be 201701. Please confirm this